# Filter a file using shell script tools

Tags: bash, unix

I have a file which contents are

```
E006:Jane:HR:9800:Asst
E005:Bob:HR:5600:Exe
E002:Barney:Purc:2300:PSE
E009:Miffy:Purc:3600:Mngr
E001:Franny:Accts:7670:Mngr
E003:Ostwald:Mrktg:4800:Trainee
E004:Pearl:Accts:1800:SSE
E009:Lala:Mrktg:6566:SE
E018:Popoye:Sales:6400:QAE
E007:Olan:Sales:5800:Asst
```

I want to fetch List all employees whose emp codes are between E001 and E018 using command including pipes is it possible to get ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use sed:

```
sed -n -e '/^E001:/,/^E018:/p' data.txt
```

That is, print the lines that are literally between those lines that start with E001 and E018.

If you want to get the employees that are numerically between those, one way to do that would be to do comparisons inline using something like awk (as suggested by hochl).  Or, you could take this approach preceded by a `sort` (if the lines are not already sorted).

```
sort data.txt | sed -n -e '/^E001:/,/^E018:/p'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `awk` for such cases:

```
$ gawk 'BEGIN { FS=":" } /^E([0-9]+)/ { n=substr($1, 2)+0; if (n >= 6 && n <= 18) { print } }' < data.txt
E006:Jane:HR:9800:Asst
E009:Miffy:Purc:3600:Mngr
E009:Lala:Mrktg:6566:SE
E018:Popoye:Sales:6400:QAE
E007:Olan:Sales:5800:Asst
```

**Is that the result you want?** This example intentionally only prints employees between 6 and 18 to show that it filters out records. You may print some fields only using `$1` or `$2` as in `print $1 " " $2`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this: `cut -b2- | awk '{ if ($1 < 18) print "E" $0 }'`

Comment: did you try to pipe the file to this script? (`cat file | ...`)

Answer (score 0):

Just do string comparison: Since all your sample data matches, I changed the boundaries for illustration

```
awk -F: '"E004" <= $1 && $1 <= "E009" {print}'
```

output

```
E006:Jane:HR:9800:Asst
E005:Bob:HR:5600:Exe
E009:Miffy:Purc:3600:Mngr
E004:Pearl:Accts:1800:SSE
E009:Lala:Mrktg:6566:SE
E007:Olan:Sales:5800:Asst
```

You can pass the strings as variables if you don't want to hard-code them in the awk script

```
awk -F: -v start=E004 -v stop=E009 'start <= $1 && $1 <= stop {print}'
```